# Window on load event on iPad, iPhone (iOS 5.1) not working

Tags: jquery, ios, ipad

Does anyone know why the `jQuery $(window).load(function() { alert("Hello!"); });` doesn't fire on iPad and iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why there's an issue with

```
jQuery $(window).load(function() { alert("Hello!"); });
```

but changing to

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {alert('Hello!');});
```

did the trick for me.